# When i press button on the game scene its starts the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my problem is I have a Shop button in the game scene so when I press it doesn't take me to the shop scene it starts the game, I want when I press the button take me to the shop scene! , I will post my code I hope you can guys help me because I spend one day reading about that and I didn't get any result PLEASE HELP!

Mobile Input script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MobileInput : MonoBehaviour {

private const float DEADZONE = 100.0f;

public static MobileInput Instance { set; get;  }

private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private Vector2 swipeDelta, startTouch;

public bool Tap { get { return tap; } }
public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }

private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}

private void Update()
{ 
    //Reseting all the booleans
    tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;

    //Let's check for inputs
    #region Stanedalone Inputs
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        tap = true;
        startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
    #endregion



    #region Mobile Inputs
    if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
    {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            tap = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        }

    }
    #endregion

    //Caluclate distance
    swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    if (startTouch != Vector2.zero)
    { 
        //Let's check with mobile 
        if (Input.touches.Length != 0)

        {
            swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
        }
        //Lets check with standalone
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
        }
    }

    //Let's check if we're beyond the deadzone 
    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > DEADZONE)
    { 
        // this is a confirmed swipe
        float x = swipeDelta.x;
        float y = swipeDelta.y;

        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            // Left or right
            if (x < 0)
                swipeLeft = true;
            else
                swipeRight = true;
        }

        else
        { 
            // Up or Down
            if (y < 0)
                swipeDown = true;
            else
                swipeUp = true;
        }

        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

}

GameManager script

```
    private void Update()
{
    if (MobileInput.Instance.Tap && !isGameStarted)
    {
        isGameStarted = true;
        motor.StartRunning();
        FindObjectOfType<GlacierSpawner>().IsScrolling = true;
        FindObjectOfType<CameraMotor>().IsMoving = true;
        gameCanvas.SetTrigger("Show");
        MenuAnim.SetTrigger("Hide");
    }
    if (isGameStarted && !isDead)
    {
        //Bump up the score 
        score += (Time.deltaTime * modifierScore);
        if (lastScore != (int)score)
        {
            lastScore = (int)score;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you indicate the `loadLevel`. I use [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html) to swap between scenes. Make sure you add your scenes to build settings.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I want is to, first I have to scenes one for the shop scene the second one for the game scene , so I'm having a problem with the game scene which is when I press the shop button it's starts the game automatically then when I disable the mobile inputs script its take me to the shop scene, so I thought there's a problem with my mobile input script

Comment: But i can't see anything relevant to swap scenes in both of the codes? Can you show me or tell me in which line of which script does this?

Comment: It starts the game because you told your game to start in your GameManager script. You aren't checking the input against anything, you're just blindly accepting **any and all** touch taps as the cue to start the game.

Comment: @draco18s Okay and how i can fix that ?

Comment: Be discriminatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an invisible UIButton to cover the screen except the ShopButton area. Define two public methods in your GameManager script, one for start game, on for show shop, and link these to methods to the UIButtons by adding an OnClick Handler in the Button Component of your UIButtons.

Don't forget to disable the PlayButton after clicking it ;)